# Pandas read csv using column names included in a list

Tags: pandas, dataframe, csv

I'm quite new to Pandas.
I'm trying to create a dataframe reading thousands of csv files.
The files are not structured in the same way, but I want to extract only columns I'm interested in, so I created a list which inlcudes all the column names I want, but then i have an error cause not all of them are included in each dataset.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import os
import glob

# select the csv folder
csv_folder= r'myPath'

# select all xlsx files within the folder
all_files = glob.glob(csv_folder + "/*.csv")

# Set the column names to include in the dataframe
columns_to_use = ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name3', 'Name4', 'Name5', 'Name6']

# read one by one all the excel
for filename in all_files:
    df = pd.read_csv(filename,
                     header=0,
                     usecols = columns_to_use)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-0d9670495660> in <module>
      1 for filename in all_files:
----> 2     df = pd.read_csv(filename,
      3                      header=0,
      4                     usecols = columns_to_use)
      5 

ValueError: Usecols do not match columns, columns expected but not found: ['Name1', 'Name2', 'Name4']
```

How could I handle this issue by including a columns if this is present in the list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usa a callable for `usecols`, i.e. `df = pd.read_csv(filename, header=0, usecols=lambda c: c in columns_to_use)`. From the [docs of the usecols parameter](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.read_csv.html):

> If callable, the callable function will be evaluated against the
> column names, returning names where the callable function evaluates to
> True.

Working example that will only read `col1` and not throw an error on missing `col3`:

```
import pandas as pd
import io

s = """col1,col2
1,2"""

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(s), usecols=lambda c: c in ['col1', 'col3'])
```